# Toshiba laptop burned after heavy OpenGL usage. Is there hope?

Tags: laptop, toshiba-laptop, maintenance

After programming for OpenGL and a 'slow OS' case for a couple of minutes the screen went blank. I shut it down with forcing it with the shutdown key and now there's no led at all with  battery or AC, it doesn't start at all, it's totally dead. It's most certainly not the AC adapter since that didn't show at first, it doesn't start a led at all and

**If the AC is connected it does a very slight and faint clicking noise** (one has to have his ear next to it to hear it, near the AC connector).

Is there any hope?

I suppose it's a burned motherboard. I suspected a burned GPU but that would still leave the leds at least lid or at least attempting to start up. Now it's totally dead.

It's a TOSHIBA satellite x200-219. It has no warranty, as it's more than 2 years since purchase.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is definitely a case for the tech-shop.

A technician might be able to see the problem, or would have the tools to track it down, or at worst have the spare-parts to try.

If I had to guess, I would say this is a problem with the PSU, as being the only part that can cause such a complete failure. However, my guess is not worth the price of a new PSU.

Have the technician check also all thermal pastes, fans and air conduits.

Comment: I think the PSU is far fetched since when it died it was a specific bug with OpenGL rendering, the battery doesn't start it at all, there's no led lid at all, there's nothing. Furthermore, the AC is not totally dead either since there's a slight noise coming from the laptop when plugged in.

Comment: @leladax The AC making noise is NEVER an indicator of its proper functioning...

Comment: It doesn't come from the AC, from the laptop near the AC connection. I'm almost sure by now something burned between the AC connection and the motherboard.

Comment: All the more reason to see a techie.

Answer (score 4):

8600m gt?, check if Toshiba is giving a extend warranty since *EVERY SINGLE* 8600m gt gpu is faulty.  (Apple, Asus and Dell have some extend plan)

If yes then fine, if not then avoid to purchase another Toshiba.

Comment: Yes, but how could that be when the laptop doesn't even have a led lid?

Comment: the nvidia 8600m gt is integrated in the motherboard. The fault is generated in some component, it fail where it switch from high temp to low temp and literally burn the component.  In some rare case, it is possible to access directly to the machine (remote desktop) but in other case the machine fail completely (it does not start at all).

Comment: I don't see how that would completely kill the laptop (not even a led). I suspect something relevant to graphics killed the powersupply to the motherboard.